# Hot to convert list type object to xml in python?

Tags: python

I have an object, which is of the list type. `print type(result)` returns `<type 'list'>`. Is there any functions for automatic conversion in to the XML ?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What does `result` look like? What schema is used to define the resulting XML?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [yattag](http://www.yattag.org) library:

```
from yattag import Doc

doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

with tag('persons'):
    for person in persons_dict:
        doc.stag('person', **person):

result = doc.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple [dict2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dict2xml) library that can do this fairly easily, even complex structure like nested list can be supported well:

Example:

```
from dict2xml import dict2xml as xmlify
data = [
    {"a": 1},
    {"a": 2},
    {"a": 3},
    {"a": [
        {"b": 1},
        {"b": 2},
        {"b": 3},
    ]}
]

print xmlify(data, wrap="all", indent="  ")
```

Result:

```
<all>
  <a>1</a>
</all>
<all>
  <a>2</a>
</all>
<all>
  <a>3</a>
</all>
<all>
  <a>
    <b>1</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>2</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>3</b>
  </a>
</all>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [`objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#creating-objectify-trees) and E-factory from `lxml`.

```
E = objectify.E
result = [{ 'a': 1 }, {'a': 2} , {'a': 3}]   
child_tags = [E.mytag(el) for el in result]
xml = E.root(*child_tags)
etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True)
```

E gives you constructor for any tag. In my example you will have tag `mytag` for each element of the list and each tag will have attributes corresponding to dict keys. So resulting xml will be:

```
<root xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype"  
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <mytag a="1"/>
  <mytag a="2"/>
  <mytag a="3"/>
</root>
```

Comment: gm, cant understand how i can use it with my `result` variable

Comment: @Kirix i updated snippet.

Comment: but this is a hadrcoded way, as all keys are `a`, but i really don't know what keys could be in object....

Comment: and also your example provides `<root xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" py:pytype="str">[&lt;Element a at 0xb6a48c5c&gt;, &lt;Element a at 0xb6a48cac&gt;, &lt;Element a at 0xb6a48cfc&gt;]</root>`

Comment: `E` gives you constructor to create any tag with any attributes you need. Check page I linked http://lxml.de/objectify.html#creating-objectify-trees

Comment: @Kirix also there was a `*` missing , slightly changed snipped so it gives you better insight on what is going on.

Comment: still bad result. Now it's like this `<mytag py:pytype="str">{'scopes': u'onvif://www.onvif.o.....`

Comment: you see you have list of some custom objects, you have to convert it to say list of dictionaries first, so they would have only data you want to have in xml. Alternatively you have to look up in docs for library you used in order to produce this list. maybe it has xml serialization internally.

Answer (score -1):

I'm beginner in Python, but I think this code will do the job & is very easy to understand :)

```
persons_list = [['Ahmed', '16', 'white'], ['Housein', '16', 'green']]

f = open('data.xml', 'w')
f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
f.write('<persons>')

for person in persons_list :
    f.write('<person>')
    f.write('<name>' + person[0] + '</name>')
    f.write('<age>' + person[1] + '</age>')
    f.write('<color> ' + person[2] + '</color>')
    f.write('</person>')

f.write('</persons>')
f.close()
```

However I think this is not the best way to do it ;)

Comment: It's generally not good practice to build XML with strings. Better to let an XML library build the structure for you.